# Position fixed changing with changing device widths

Tags: css, media-queries, css-position, fixed

Some weird stuff is happening with a `position:fixed` element.

When the viewport is at width 760px, the fixed position element seems to inherit position:absolute.  Instead of it `taking top:5em`, `botttom:5em` from the viewport.  It extends to the whole page.  If an element has position fixed it shouldn't matter what position a parent element has, right? Why is this happening?

I have several media queries that affect some of the parent divs, but should this affect a `positon:fixed` element.

You can see it [here](http://durangoshadecompany.com/products-new/exterior-shades/) when you click on "Click for More Info".

Comment: We'd appreciate it if you create a fiddle http://jsfiddle.net

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When looking at your code in Chrome's developer tools, I noticed that when I disable the following CSS code, the fixed position sizing works as expected again.

```
-webkit-transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
-moz-transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
-ms-transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
-o-transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);

-webkit-transition: -webkit-transform 500ms ease;
-moz-transition: -moz-transform 500ms ease;
-o-transition: -o-transform 500ms ease;
transition: transform 500ms ease;

-webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
-moz-backface-visibility: hidden;
-ms-backface-visibility: hidden;
-o-backface-visibility: hidden;
backface-visibility: hidden;
```

This is inside the `.csstransforms3d.csstransitions.js-ready #inner-wrap` properties inside the `@media screen and (max-width: 47.5em)` query of `style.css`.